# GNU Make: % doesn't match dotted filenames?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) claims that a `%` in a pattern rule will match anything. Looks like that's not true:

```
$ ls
config.sh.in  foo.in  Makefile
$ cat Makefile
%: %.in
        cp $< $@
$ make foo
cp foo.in foo
$ make config.sh
make: *** No rule to make target 'config.sh'.  Stop.
$
```

What gives?

Comment: You should be aware that  Match-Anything rules (`%:`) can severely slow down make on larger projects.    [see here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem

It will actually match anything. The problem is that GNU Make by default generates the following:

```
%.sh:
```

Which is a [*built-in dummy pattern rule*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules) (note that is has no recipe). That prevents make from matching a *non-specific* target pattern, i.e.: a target pattern other than `%.sh` (like yours).

---

#### Solution

Since dummy pattern rules are generated for each suffix found in the built-in [`.SUFFIXES`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html) target, you can either explicitly write an empty  `.SUFFIXES` target in your makefile (as shown below), or simply run `make` with the command-line option `-r` or `--no-builtin-rules` in order to disable the generation of such dummy built-in pattern rules.

```
.SUFFIXES:
%: %.in
        cp $< $@
```

This way, the following:

```
$ make config.sh
cp config.sh.in config.sh
```

works as you expected.

Comment: That's it. Thanks much :)